# Valid Url in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, url

I'm using code igniter, now it does not have any validation method to validate url so i applied this code

```
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
{
 $this->form_validation->set_message(__FUNCTION__,'The field %s must be a valid url');
 return FALSE;
}
else
{
   return TRUE; 
}
```

now it's working fine for links that include `http://google.com` or `https://www.google.com` but also for `http://google` without .com, how to solve this

Comment: That is a valid URL. But what you can do is start with filter_var and, if it passes, do additionally verification for the TLD.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) in the codeigniter documentation. There is a `valid_url` function.